# Why print 'NaN' value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I study JavaScript, but I have something wrong with my code that is written by **JavaScript**.
Of course, I think I know what `NaN` is.
It might be `Not A Number`. isn't it?

I know my code is not good as attached below, but could you look at the code below?
*First*,

```js
var scores = {
  val1: 90,
  val2: 100,
  val3: 98,
  val4: 95
}

function calcAverage() {
  var sum, size = 0;
  for (var key in this) {
    sum += this[key];
    size++;
  }
  return sum / size;
}
console.log(calcAverage.apply(scores));
```

I thought it would be printed `95.75` as a result.
But It was `Nan`, not `95.75`.

*Second*,

```js
var scores = {
  val1: 90,
  val2: 100,
  val3: 98,
  val4: 95
}

function calcAverage() {
  var sum = 0;
  var size = 0;
  for (var key in this) {
    sum += this[key];
    size++;
  }
  return sum / size;
}
console.log(calcAverage.apply(scores));
```

But, this code printed `95.75` well. I'm confused why the first code has wrong. So, What is the difference with first code and second code?

Comment: You didn't initialize sum = 0 in the first code.

Comment: `var sum, size = 0;` only sets size to 0, not sum. That is undefined, so divide retutns NaN

Comment: Thank you @isaacsan123  It's just my fault.

Comment: thx @shree.pat18 I didn't know that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Replace , with = it will also work fine! Initialize variable

```js
var scores = {
  val1: 90,
  val2: 100,
  val3: 98,
  val4: 95
}

function calcAverage() {
  var sum = size = 0;
  for (var key in this) {
    sum += this[key];
    size++;
  }
  return sum / size;
}
console.log(calcAverage.apply(scores));
```

Comment: You created a global variable `size` https://jsfiddle.net/m4rqLp2a/

Comment: thx I didn't know that too. @Samathingamajig

Comment: I have updated the above code to a working code,it was returning Nan, i have just change the way of declaring variable

Comment: @tusharwason But your change is flawed because it pollutes the global namespace adding a global variable `size`

Comment: Throws error in strict mode because of implicit global.